# MQ-FTE options for email alerting on errors or monitoring (to be able to support the solution during Test and then Prod Support)?

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

In the latest version of MQ-FTE are there any new out of the box options for email alerting on errors or monitoring (to be able to support the solution during Test and then Prod Support)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an FTE Ant sample that sends an email if the transfer fails; see this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/sample_ant_tasks.htm).

Alternatively, you could create a subscription to FTE's log publications and have an application read publications from the subscription queue; if a publication reports a failed transfer, your application could then send an email.  See this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/system_fte.htm) for information about these publications.